# drag and drop between mat-accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng2-dragula

I am trying to make drag and drop between mat-accordion. Problem is as long accordion is closed i am not able to drop any item to it.

Here is my code

```
public groups: Array<any> = [
  {
    name: 'Group A',
    items: [{name: 'Item A'}, {name: 'Item B'}, {name: 'Item C'}, {name: 'Item D'}]
  },
  {
    name: 'Group B',
    items: [{name: 'Item 1'}, {name: 'Item 2'}, {name: 'Item 3'}, {name: 'Item 4'}]
  }
];
```

Html

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor='let group of groups'>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        {{group.name}}
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div *ngFor='let item of group.items' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
        <div>{{item.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Note: drag and drop is working fine if I drag and drop item to the same container but I want to be able to drop to closed accordion, line when I start drag accordion other accordion open and I can drop there.

Comment: can you replicate this issue in stackblitz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue.
For now, I have solved it using CSS.
Go to the dragula css file :- node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css

```
.gu-mirror {
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

If you will comment this position then you will not see the strange behaviour which you are facing.
Although, I am not css expert. but to solve it you can adjust the margin so that your drag text and cursor should not overlap. Give some margin.

```
margin: 0  0 0 100px !important;
```